# Why do I keep getting this message? "This question body does not meet our quality standards."

Tags: support

I'm trying to submit a question and I keep getting this message:

> #### Request failed
>
> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

I tried to change the body but it keeps popping up..!?!

Here is a screen shot of the error message:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Can you edit this question to include the text of the question you wanted to post?  If we can see what you wanted to ask, we can try to figure out why the site is giving you that error message.

Comment: @snailplane do we say 90's or 90s' burgers? That's what the question's body contained.

Comment: It is most likely too brief, containing too few characters.

Comment: To overcome the character, and the low quality limit, is not such a difficult task and within everyone's capabilities. See:  [Please, everyone… details. Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) 1. `Provide as much context as possible` 2. `Explain why you are confused.` 3. `Show your research.`

Comment: You want to know how it is *written* not how it is said, and therefore you're really asking about the apostrophe, if it is needed or not, and "why". Is the apostrophe denoting plurality or possessiveness? The question has nothing to do with grammar but everything to do with punctuation. It would also be interesting to know "why" you are asking about hamburgers in the 1980s. (I prefer writing decades without the apostrophe)

Comment: OK, an update would have been nice, telling visitors that you posted the question...  I've just seen it. Spartan, but essential. If you included "why" you thought the apostrophe is necessary, you'd generate more interest.